# command_runner elevate() function is not working with os.symlink (OSError: [WinError 1314])

Tags: python, symlink, elevated-privileges, elevation

I am using the [command_runner](https://pypi.org/project/command-runner/) module in order to elevate to admin rights when creating a `symlink`.

```
import os

from command_runner.elevate import elevate


def main():
    """Entry point"""
    source = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Toto")
    dest = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Tata")

    if not os.path.exists(source):
        os.mkdir(source)

    os.symlink(source, dest)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    elevate(main)
```

However, if my windows command prompt is not started as admin, it does not work:

> OSError: [WinError 1314] A required privilege is not held by the
> client

I am also using the elevate command at an other occasion, to create a file in a windows protected folder, and it works very well here (I elevate only the `main`).

So I wonder how to fix this particular case ?

Comment: Do you have write privileges on that file ? I'll happily try to reproduce if not

Comment: I need admin rights, which I have as an user but the command windows did not have as not started as admin. From the command_runner documentation, it should give admin rights to the process

Comment: Yes, but the question was if you have NTFS privileges as admin. Execute the script from an already elevated window to see whather that is the culprit